# Build xcode projects from terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, swift4, xcode9

When I build Xcode projects from the command line :

```
 xcodebuild -workspace project_name.xcworkspace -sdk iphones BUILD_DIR = "build" -configuration Release -scheme Project_scheme build
```

I get following errors in Xcode 9 with swift 4

```
Compileswift normal x86_64 /project_path/someswift.swft
CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
```

When I build project instead of workspace also it gives the same error. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try turning off whole module optimization, please.

Comment: Did not help turning off wmo

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. Found that solution via google.